# What is the rationale behind the iterator/sentinel of range adaptors providing the base() accessor?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

Legacy iterator adaptors such as `reverse_iterator` and `move_iterator`, or C++20/23 newly introduced adaptors such as `counted_iterator`, `basic_const_iterator`, and `move_sentinel`, all of them provide `base()` member to allow us to access the underlying iterator/sentinel:

```
constexpr const I& base() const& noexcept { return current_­; }
constexpr I        base() &&              { return std​::​move(current_­); }
```

However, for a series of iterators/sentinels of range adaptors in `<ranges>`, I found that they do not all provide a `base()`. For example, `split_view`'s "outer-iterator" provides a `base()`, while `lazy_split_view` does not ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yev518Weo)):

```
string_view s = "one two three four";

// ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
auto r1 = s | views::split(' ');
for (auto it = r1.begin(); it != r1.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it.base() << " ";      // prints 'o' 't' 't' 'f'

// ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
auto r2 = s | views::lazy_split(' ');
for (auto it = r2.begin(); it != r2.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it.base() << " ";      // error, no 'base' member
```

As another example, `chunk_view::iterator` provides a `base()`, but `slide_view::iterator`, which also belongs to windowing range adaptors, does not ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8vx9j69sj)):

```
array v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
auto r1 = v | views::chunk(2);
for (auto it = r1.begin(); it != r1.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it.base() << " ";      // prints 1 3 5 

// [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
auto r2 = v | views::slide(2);
for (auto it = r2.begin(); it != r2.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it.base() << " ";      // error, no 'base' member
```

And for sentinel adaptors, there also seem to be inconsistencies: both `filter_view/transform_view::sentinel` provide `base()`, but `join_view/split_view::sentienl` with the same layout do not.

So, what is the rationale for these iterator/sentinel adaptors that provide the `base()`? I could not find any considerations behind this from historical documents, so I'm wondering what design philosophy the standard is based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, I deliberately did not provide `base()` when doing so could leak implementation details (`zip` and `adjacent` - we don't want to mandate any particular form of iterator storage) and/or be confusing (`chunk_view::outer-iterator` - `base()` will change while you iterate over the chunk, because that's the only way to implement this for input iterators).

`lazy_split`'s outer-iterator - at least for input ranges - would have the same problem as `chunk`.

I probably didn't provide `base()` for `slide` because I didn't provide it for `adjacent`, but it should be fine to add it.

There's nothing meaningful you can do with a `join_view`'s sentinel's wrapped sentinel (the iterator doesn't provide `base()` - and for good reasons), so there's no motivation to provide access to it. It's probably reasonable to provide `base()` for `split`'s sentinel though, since we provided one for its iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening explanation. For `adjacent_view::iterator`, is it reasonable to provide a `base()` that returns `array.front()`? Although compared to `spill_view`, I can't really think of a use case for `slide`/`adjacent`'s outer-iterator to provide such utility.

Comment: That leaks an implementation detail for non-bidirectional common ranges (you can have `i == j` but `i.base() != j.base()`).

Comment: That would be confusing. But does this mean that `slide_view` will have the same similar issue? According to its implementation details, if we provide `base()` for its iterator, for `list`, `r.end().base()` points to a valid element, and for `forward_list`, `r.end().base ()` refers to its actual `end()`, which seems confusing. It seems that only `split_view::sentinel/chunk_by_view::iterator` is worth adding `base()`, is that correct?